# UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning transtionsDuration and UIView.Animate

Tags: ios, uikit, uiviewanimationtransition

I have a subclass of UIViewControllerAnimatingTransitioning which defines an animations in a method animateTransitioning(using:) with UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) and second one UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 0.5, options: .curveEaseIn). The UIViewControllerAnimatingTransitioning requires a second method which is transitionDuration(using:) which should return a duration.

How duration defined in transitionDuration(using:) impact the duration defined in UIView.animation(withDuration)?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation provided by Apple for the `transitionDuration(using:)` method [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontrolleranimatedtransitioning/1622032-transitionduration), the duration you return is used to synchronize other potential animations and "actions".

> UIKit uses the value to synchronize the actions of other objects that might be involved in the transition. For example, a navigation controller uses the value to synchronize changes to the navigation bar.

In your scenario where there are two different `UIView.animate` blocks, you should return the time it takes for the longest animation to complete. Below is the explanation on how to calculate this. Assume both animations start at `t = 0`, where `t` is time in seconds.

```
totalAnimationDuration = delay + duration
```

1. First animation starts at, t = 0 and completes after 1 second.
2. Second animation starts at, t = 0.5 and completes after 2 seconds.

```swift
let animOneTotalDuration = 0 + 1 // 1 second
let animTwoTotalDuration = 0.5 + 2 // 2.5 seconds
```

Since the animation that has the maximum total time is the second animation, you should return `2.5` at `transitionDuration(using:)`.

It should also be noted that setting the animation duration correctly does not automatically complete the transition after the duration. You must still invoke the `completeTransition(_:)` of the `UIViewControllerContextTransitioning` object you receive at `animateTransition(using:)`.

Hope I was able to give you some insight!